# Is legal to make a post promoting an affiliate link for a product or service I did not test?

Tags: advertising, legal, affiliate, post

Can I put affiliate links on my site without first testing the product or services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to read FTC's **".com Disclosures"** guidelines document on affiliate links and what to keep in mind in terms of disclosures:

https://www.ftc.gov/sites/default/files/attachments/press-releases/ftc-staff-revises-online-advertising-disclosure-guidelines/130312dotcomdisclosures.pdf

Note that you need to properly disclose your affiliate links in a prominent way: "clear and conspicuous".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the legal point depends on the country you are.
But to me, you don't care. It's not a question about is it legal or not, it's a credibility question. If you suggest your visitor to buy something and if this thing is realy bad qualety you will receive bad feedback and bad visibility / seo.

Comment: I see, but what if you know it's not bad quality.

I will be more specific. Can have your site hosted at CloudFlare and promote BlueHost without ever trying it yourself?

Comment: Please, allow me to answer with a question : do you realy think all bloger and youtuber have tested all the product they promote on blog article or you tube? Think about sponsored article, same case.

Comment: Good point. But "should" they try it before recommending it or they can just advertise if they it's not bad?